# Add multiple buttons to IOS7 Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

How would I go about adding several buttons to a tableview to each cell? I need to add a comment and like button to each cell in my tableview and each button will have to be specfic to the row being clicked. How do I go about doing something like this ?  Do i place a action inside of

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

or is there a way to programatically set a button to a ibaction from inside cellForRowAtIndexPath that allows me to send parameters?

Comment: There are vast numbers of tutorials in `iTunes U` or on the web about how to create a custom `UITableViewCell` and program using `Objective C` and `Cocoa Touch`.  A good place to start (beyond the Stanford course on iTunes U) is Ray Wenderlich's site: http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: This was not the question, im well aware of how to create a custom table cell, the problem is getting "objectAtIndex" passed into the action so that ik which status is being clicked.

Comment: The first part of question was `How would I go about adding several buttons to a tableview to each cell?` which is answered. The second part I don't fully understand as it's not very clear but I would have the `UITableViewCell` subclass handle the `IBAction` inside itself. If you then need to send data back to the `UITableViewController` you can use a delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom table view cell and add multiple button.
1. Create class that subclasses UITableviewcell with xib
2. In xib delete the view and drag a tableview cell into xib
3. Add multiple buttons in xib
4. Create IBOutlet for each button.
5. In your view controller import your CustomTableViewCell and in CellForRowAtIndexPath method add action for each method and set button tag as indexpath.row
6. Identify the clicked button's indexpath from it's tag

[Refer this link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

I think this is what you are asking...

```
[cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                                 In the
```

receiver method you can get sender's tag

```
-(void)button1Pressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton*)sender; 
    int selectedRow = sender.tag;
}
```

Comment: This s close , but im loosing you when you say "and in CellForRowAtIndexPath method add action for each method and set button tag as indexpath.row 6 "   ik how to link the buttons up to a action , but im not sure how to also let that action know what row is being clicked. a snippet would be extremely helpful

Comment: I think this is what you are asking...                                    [cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                                 In the receiver method you can get sender's tag                         -(void)button1Pressed:(id)sender{UIButton *button1 = (UIButton*)sender; int selectedRow = sender.tag;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass your UITableViewCell so you can customise it to your need.

There are a lot of tutorials about this. Depends if you are using Storyboard or not. Here is one of many: http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells

Comment: I was aware of how to subclass the cell and create custom cells, but it doesnt really answer my question in any clear way. I would need the actions i connect to know what row was clicked so that i could grab the right data from the api response that was used to create the tableview so that i can take the appropriate action

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You create 2 buttons in your cell, connect them to an action in your cell subclass and from there you can then see which row was selected.